# .bind() doesn't work for functions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use variables placed inside a function. I'm not looking to do anything particular with this piece of code, but I want to figure out why bind / apply / call work for objects, and not functions.

```
function another () {
    this.var = 'another test'
}

function test (){
    this.var = 'test123'
    console.log('this.first: ',this.var);
}

var bind = test.bind(another);
console.log('bind: ', bind());
```

Comment: If you check `another.var` after running this, you should see it set to `'test123'`.  What were you expecting?

Comment: To print the variable from another() = 'another test'

Comment: Why, when you overwrite it with `'test123'` before you log anything?

Comment: it's bound to the function another

Comment: Now you can check `another.var` to be `'test123'` :)

Comment: No, it's bound to the *object* `another`, which happens to be a Function.

Comment: The code in the function `another` is never executed, so the string `'another test'` is not assigned to anything. You can't output a value that doesn't exist. You are writing out what the `test` function returns, but it doesn't return any value.

Comment: If I call another() before assignment of bind = ~~ , I still do not get the variable from another() . At this point the variable does exist. Does not calling bind() call test again with the variable from another?  Can someone post an example?

Comment: Nop, `bind` doesn't call the function, it creates a partially applied function to be called.

Comment: @seasick: No. The [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns a new function that executes the original one, bound to a context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.bind()` works just fine for functions.  It just doesn't do what you think it does.

See, functions are objects too.  And treating them like objects doesn't mean they get called.

```
function a() { console.log("a was called"); }
function b() { console.log(this); }

var bound = b.bind(a);
bound();  // logs "function a() { }" in my console
```

In your case, once you've bound `test` to `another`, you have a new function that works just like `test`, but where `this` means `another`, and thus `this.var` means `another.var`.  And all of this happens without `another` *ever getting called*.

I'm not sure entirely how you expect your code to work, cause it doesn't make much sense as it stands.  But if you were to examine things after you run it, you would find that `another.var` now has the value `'test123'`.

Even if you said `another()` beforehand, it wouldn't matter.  Firstly because `another` isn't bound to anything, so to it, `this` means the global object.  In a browser, `another()` would basically just be setting `window.var`.  But secondly, `test` sets its own value -- so even if both functions had the same idea of what `this.var` means, `test` would overwrite it with `'test123'`.

Answer (score 1):

This will log "another test", since `this` defaults to `window`:

```
function another() {
    this.foo = 'another test';
}

another();

console.log(window.foo);
```

edit:

```
// define function object window.first:
function first() {
    this.foo = 'first';
}

// define function object window.second:
function second() {
    this.foo = 'second';
}

// call window.first, sets window.foo to 'first':
first();

// set window.bound to a new function object which
// runs second in the context of the object first:
var bound = second.bind(first);

// call window.bound, which sets window.first.foo to 'second':
bound();

// call second, which sets window.foo to 'second' then logs the return
// value of second, which is undefined:
console.log('second: ', second());
```

Comment: Please also explain why you shouldn't do this.

Comment: It isn't self-evident? :-)

Comment: Yeah, `s/explain why/state that/` after your edit :-)

Comment: @seasick: Do tell. What did you expect it to do

Comment: I called another(), then bound it to another, then called the newly bound function

Comment: I've added in an example along the lines of the comment above.